# Undefined method 'stringify_keys' error when using many to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

There are lots of stringify_keys questions here, but i can't find proper match to my problem, so i'll appreciate at least any example matching it.

I have three models named Song, Mixtape and MixtapeSong.

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :duration, :name, :order

  belongs_to :album

  has_many :mixtape_songs
  has_many :mixtapes, :through => :mixtape_songs
end

class Mixtape < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :image, :name

  has_many :mixtape_songs
  has_many :songs, :through => :mixtape_songs
end

class MixtapeSong < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :mixtape_id, :order, :song_id
  belongs_to :mixtape
  belongs_to :song
end
```

When i tried below commands through rails console, i succeed to add a record to mixtape_songs table with mixtape_id and song_id values but also with an 'order' NULL:

```
mtape = Mixtape.find(1)
song  = Song.find(3)
mtape.songs << song
```

Also executing an update_attributes was failed with 'Undefined method signify_keys' error.

```
params = [:mixtape_id => 1, :song_id => 3, :order => 2]
mts = MixtapeSong.find(1)
mts.update_attributes(params)
```

What i need to do is adding this association through Mixtape model with specifying an 'order' value or through MixtapeSong model without 'Undefined method signify_keys' error.

I guess the right way is adding through Mixtape model but i can't figure out how to set 'order'? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wrong brackets! Use curly ones: `{:mixtape_id => 1, :song_id => 3, :order => 2}`

Comment: Thanks @jdoe, i corrected it and it worked. Is there any way to do it through Mixtape or Song model? Or since i have an extra field other than the associated fields, do i have to use MixtapeSong in order to insert/update 'order' val?

Comment: Am I right that you need to fetch your songs for a specific Mixtape in the order you used to "insert" them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetching:

```
mtape = Mixtape.find(1)
songs_in_proper_order = mtape.songs.order(mixtape_songs: :created_at)
```

Swapping:

```
MixtapeSong.transaction do
    ms1 = MixtapeSong.find(1)
    ms2 = MixtapeSong.find(2)

    ms1.created_at, ms2.created_at = ms2.created_at, ms1.created_at

    ms1.save
    ms2.save
end
```

Comment: That's right, but what if i need to reorder songs after i created it?

Comment: That's why I asked you about your intentions! You didn't mention this possibility :) But any way, if you want to swap 2 songs, just swap `:created_at` of their mixtape_songs. And you need to order songs by `:created_at` instead of `:id`.

Comment: Ok, ordering with `:created_at` is a solution for not to use extra field except association fields. i will try this, thanks :)

Comment: Not "overriding". It is created by Rails for you and it should stay this way. Maybe that's what you meant, but worth noting.